Is there a way to short a low voltage circuit remotely without physically touching it?
I'm looking for a way to short a low voltage circuit remotely without having to physically make contact with it. A preinstalled discharge or shorting circuit can't exist in this case. Just any random circuit and then being able to short it remotely.

yes, there is a way

@jsotola I'll like to hear it.

need more context

Hose it down with salt water? What kind of answer are you hoping for?

@TechDroid that is not what you asked ... this site is not a chat forum ... ask the question that you would like answered ... please use the edit button to update your question

Yes, you can shoot a drone with a shotgun. Vote to close unless a sensible scenario can be added to the main question.

This question needs more context.  Otherwise it is just opinions.

If the remote system is not in a vacuum, you could ionize the matter surrounding it using a laser. Whether the laserbeam constitutes 'physical contact' may be considered a matter of opinion.
